# Python multiple pairs replace in txt file

Tags: python, text, substitution

I've got 2 .txt files, the first one is organized like this:

```
1:NAME1
2:NAME2
3:NAME3
...
```

and the second one like this:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
```

What I want to do is to substitute every line in .txt 2 according to pairs in .txt 1, like this:

```
NAME1
NAME1
NAME1
NAME2
NAME2
NAME2
NAME3
```

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking to organize the first txt deleting the 1: 2: 3: and read it as an array, then make a loop for i in range(1, number of lines in txt 1) and then in the txt 2 find lines containing "i" and substituting with the i-element of the array. But of course I've no idea how to do this.

Comment: Just store file 1 records on dictionary, file 2 have the key of dict and you should replace with value ie dict[key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rodrigo commented. There are many ways to implement it, but storing the names in a dictionary is probably the way to go.

```
# Read the names
with open('names.txt') as f_names:
    names = dict(line.strip().split(':') for line in f_names)

# Read the numbers
with open('numbers.txt') as f_numbers:
    numbers = list(line.strip() for line in f_numbers)

# Replace numbers with names
with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for n in numbers:
        f_output.write(names[n] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It reads the first file and stores the `k, v` pairs in a dict. That dict is the used to output the `v` for every `k` you find in the second file.

But.... if you want to prevent these downvotes it is better to post a code snippet of your own to show what you have tried... Right now your question is a red blanket for the horde of SO'ers that downvote everything that has no code in it. Hell, they even downvote answers because there is no code in the question...

```
lookup = {}
with open("first.txt") as fifile:
    for line in fifile:
        lookup[line.split[":"][0]] = line.split[":"][1] 

with open("second.txt") as sifile:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as ofile:
        for line in sifile:
            ofile.write("{}\n".format(lookup[line])
```

Comment: Haven't tried yours but jrmyp's code worked perfectly. Dunno what's people's problem with this downvoting, I got an idea but didn't knew how to code it, that's why I ask here! Thank you by the way